# Android adaper NotifyDataSetChange Not Working

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to refresh my listview after deleting a item from it. Even tho I'm using notifyDataSetChanged it still not updating instantly. I need to go back and come again to this intent. Need Help. Thanks in advance.

```
viewData();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {
            alart=new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewData.this);
            alart.setTitle("Are you sure?");
            alart.setMessage("Are you sure want to clear  this data?");
            alart.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    boolean ans=mydb.deleteTitle(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"->"+ans,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                
            });
            alart.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog a = alart.create();
            a.show();
        }
    });

}

public void viewData() {
    Cursor res = mydb.getData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(ViewData.this, "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else {
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            arrayemail.add(res.getString(1) + "\n");
            arraypass.add(res.getString(2) + "\n");
        }
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, arrayemail, arraypass);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're deleting out of your database, but you're not removing an item out of your adapter:

```
 boolean ans=mydb.deleteTitle(position); //this doesn't actually change the adapter, just the database.
```

So either

1. remove out of your adapter when you delete from the db, then call notify changed, inside your `onClick` method
2. call `viewData()` after removing an item from the list, also inside `onClick`, which will create a completely new adapter which reads from your database again (this probably isn't the approach you should take)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I used the first one.